# phpactiverecord one to many assosiation

Tags: php, database, activerecord, associations

I'm using phpactiverecord for this project, I have this db structure:

**Tables: Tickets, Labels**

I'm currently using a has_many association for these two tables: "Tickets has many labels", however I need to assign each label to different ticket, which is not possible at the moment without having duplicated rows with different id and ticket_id values.

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Cheers

Comment: You can probably have a bridge table between Tickets and Labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create additional table

```
 table Label2Tickets (`label_id`, `ticket_id`, PRIMARY KEY (`label_id`, `ticket_id`)
 \* there you may store date of create, status and etc *\ 
 `created`, `status`, `user_id` ... )
```

And update existing AR and create new AR for this table:

Ticket HAS MANY Label2Tickets where Label2Tickets.ticket_id = Tickets.id
Label HAS MANY Label2Tickets where Label2Tickets.label_id = Labels.id

Comment: I knew of this possibility but I find having an additional table for this is too much hassle and not too efficient. Some sort of label_id array within the ticket row might do, but I'm still figuring out how to do so the right way.

Comment: this will do for now, but I'm going to find a more efficient way.

Comment: @proxdeveloper, do not reinvent the wheel! )) It's almost effective and I know only one way without dublicate Label's row

Comment: this is the most efficient method for a many to many relationship